# How to prevent set sate in unmounted component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I received a warning: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component", so I try to determine when my component is unmounted, like below:

```
function ListStock() {

    let mounted = true;

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const {start_date, end_date} = search;
            const result = await getDataStock(start_date, end_date);
            
            if (result && mounted) {
                setData(result.data);  // only set a state when mounted = true
            }
        }

        fetchData();

        return () => {
            mounted = false; // set false on clean up
        }

    }, [search])

    const handleSearch = () => {
        ...
        setSearch({
            start_date: moment().subtract(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            end_date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="keyword">
            <input type="button" onlick={handleSearch} value="Search">
            {data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

By this way, it can resolve that warning message, however it shows another one:

> "Assignments to the 'mounted' variable from inside React Hook
> useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over
> time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the
> '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly
> inside useEffect"

When I store the 'mounted' variable in a useRef hook, I cannot search anymore, since the 'mounted' is always set to "false".

My questions are:

- Why a clean up code runs when User click a search button? I though it runs only when a component is unmounted?
- What is the right way to implement a searching job with a remote api?
- Is it fine if I config ESLint to ignore all this kind of warning messages?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing the whole mounted/unmounted thing wrong. Here is a proper implementation:

```
const mounted = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  mounted.current = true;
  return () => {
    mounted.current = false;
  };
}, []); // Notice lack of dependencies
```

**Before I go on, I should probably refer you to the awesome [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) library, which already comes with a [`useMountedState`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useMountedState.md) hook**

Now back to your questions

- > Why a clean up code runs when User click a search button? I though it
  > runs only when a component is unmounted?

  I didn't realize this was a thing until I read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1):

  > **When exactly does React clean up an effect?** React performs the cleanup
  > when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, ***effects
  > run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans
  > up effects from the previous render before running the effects next
  > time***...

  So there you have it: The cleanup function is run after every render which happens after state changes, thus when `search` changes, a re-render is required.
- > What is the right way to implement a searching job with a remote api?

  The way you are doing it is fine, but if you are going to be checking for `unmounted` state every time, you might as well use the library I mentioned.
- > Is it fine if I config ESLint to ignore all this kind of warning
  > messages?

  Nah. Just fix it. It is very easy

Comment: I used to take advantage of `useRef()` for this very purpose too, but it seems like regular variable is just fine as well. What do you think?

Comment: @RoboRobok indeed you're right. A global variable declared with `let` would do just as well: `let mounted = false`

Comment: I think it doesn't even need to be global. If you declare it inside `useEffect()` and then read it inside returned cleanup function, it works as expected as well, due to how scoping works in JavaScript.

Comment: @RoboRobok that also works and is tidier than using global variables.

Comment: Yeah :) By the way, I wonder why does Stack Overflow sometimes hint a username when I start writing an @ character, and at other times it doesn't. This time it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a variable, you need to store  `mounted = true;` in a useRef hook. UseRef can hold values and it won't re-render the page when the value changes.

```
function ListStock() {
    const mounted = useRef(true);

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const {start_date, end_date} = search;
            const result = await getDataStock(start_date, end_date);
            
            if (result && mounted,current) {
                setData(result.data);  // only set a state when mounted = true
            }
        }

        fetchData();

        return () => {
            mounted.current = false; // set false on clean up
        }

    }, [search])

    const handleSearch = () => {
        ...
        setSearch({
            start_date: moment().subtract(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            end_date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="keyword">
            <input type="button" onlick={handleSearch} value="Search">
            {data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hopefully, questions 1 and 2 will be solved by the above code. 3rd question, I would say it's better to keep it as it shows what's going wrong.

Comment: It will not work as expected, since the useEffect function will re-run every time the "search" state changes and that makes the clean-up code runs, and so the "mounted" = false

Answer (score 0):

in this case, put mounted inside useEffect is better,
once search changed, previous request should be cancel,

```js
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        let cancel = true;
        async function fetchData() {
            const {start_date, end_date} = search;
            const result = await getDataStock(start_date, end_date);
            
            if (result && !cancel) {
                setData(result.data);  // only set a state when not canceled
            }
        }

        fetchData();

        return () => {
            cancel = true; // to cancel setState
        }

    }, [search])
```